# GEt the X axis value of hovered data point

Tags: c3.js

When the user hovers ove a data point in a line graph, I want to get the X axis value of that specfic data point so that I can position the tooltip based on that value. Is there a way i can do this? The idea is to get the value in X and subtract the tooltip container width to position it left of that point, to avoid problems with the tooltip covering the data.

My code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/owhxgaqm/292/

```
// c3 - custom tooltip
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart-test',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
            ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 3000000000000], ]
    },
    tooltip: {
         position: function(data, width, height, thisElement) {
          var containerWidth, tooltipWidth, x, y;
          element = document.getElementById("chart-test");
          containerWidth = element.clientWidth;
          tooltipWidth = element.querySelector('.c3-tooltip').clientWidth * 2;
          x = parseInt(thisElement.getAttribute('x'));
          console.log("x is " + x)
          console.log("tooltipWidth is " + tooltipWidth)
          console.log("data is " + data)
          console.log("thisElement is " + thisElement)
          if (x + tooltipWidth > containerWidth) {
            x = containerWidth - tooltipWidth - 2;
          }
          y = thisElement.getAttribute('y');
          y = y - height;
          return {
            top: y,
            left: x
          };
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help !!!

```
tooltip: {
    show: true,
    grouped: true,
    contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
            var $$ = this, config = $$.config, titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat, nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) {
                            return name;
                    }, valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat, text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;
            for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                    if (!(d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) {
                            continue;
                    }
                    if (!text) {
                            title = titleFormat ? titleFormat(d[i].x) : d[i].x;
                            text = '<table class=\'' + $$.CLASS.tooltip + '\'>' + (title || title === 0 ? '<tr><th colspan=\'2\'>' + title + '</th></tr>' : '');
                    }
                    name = d[i].name;
                    value = d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index;
                    bgcolor = $$.levelColor ? $$.levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);
                    text += '<tr class=\'' + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + '-' + d[i].id + '\'>';
                    text += '<td class=\'name\'><span style=\'background-color:' + bgcolor + '\'></span>' + name + '</td>';
                    text += '<td class=\'value\'>' + value + '</td>';
                    text += '</tr>';
            }
            return text + '</table>';
    }
}
```

The code above is used to manipulate the content which is exactly the original contents and can be modified accordingly by editing.
Specific to your problem, may be you can give padding to avoid overlapping of the tool-tip with the data points. Simply specify the style on the Table Markup above.